# How to collect/sort items from a database with the same category name?

Tags: python, django

I have been creating a Hackernews type clone recently and bumped into some trouble with my database layout and views.

Basically, a user can post a story and choose only one category for each story. Here are my models:

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.category_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories"


class Story(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    url = models.URLField()
    points = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    moderator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'moderated_stories')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name = 'categories')
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'liked_stories')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    @property 
    def domain(self):
        return urlparse(self.url).netloc

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "stories"
```

Firstly, I would just like to confirm that this is the way it should be layed out?

This then leads onto my second problem. I want to collect all the stories that belong to a particular Category and display them at their respective urls (i.e. localhost/engineering would show all the stories within the engineering category).

Here is my view/urls so far. All it does is assign each category in the database its own url.

**url.py**

```
url(r'^(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'stories.views.category'),
```

**views.py**

```
def category(request, category_id=1):
    template = 'stories/category.html'
    category = Category.objects.get(id = category_id)
    return render_to_response(template, {
        'category': category
        })
```

What could I add to my Category view such that I collect all the stories with the same category to display within my template?

Apologies if something didn't make sense, I'm only quite new to Django.

Comment: the `related_name` argument to `ForeignKey` is the name under which the relation will be known *from the other side*, so `category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name = 'categories')` really doesn't make sense - you don't want to use `category.categories.all()` to get *stories* from your category, do you ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes ,you can use `set`for [reverse relation (related objects)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#related-objects) in the templates too:

### In the template

```
{{ for cat_story in category.story_set.all }}
    {{cat_story.title }}
    {{cat_story.url }}
    ...
{{ endfor }}
```

Update: Ah, you used `reated_name`, then you should use `categories` instead of `story_set`. Try `category.categories.all` instead of `category.story_set.all`.

```
{{ for cat_story in category.categories.all }}
    {{cat_story.title }}
    {{cat_story.url }}
    ...
{{ endfor }}
```

**Update**: Yes you can, django database api usage is nearly the same in both views and in the templates. You can check related [documentation from here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

Above page shows below examples:

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

article1.publications.all()
publication2.article_set.all()
```

You can use similar syntax in the templates without the parenthesis

```
{{ for publication in  article1.publications.all }}

{{ for article in publication2.article_set.all }}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work! Is there anything in my views and/or models that should be changed?

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: Can you use this same logic for a ManyToManyField? @FallenAngel